# PayPal REST API Get Billing Plan ID with Billing Agreement ID

Tags: php, json, rest, paypal

Ok, so simple question, I have the Billing Agreement ID saved in my DB but I need the ID of the Billing Plan that is associated with it. Is is possible to get that ID?

Note that when I retrieve the Billing Agreement from the API I get a Billing Plan object in the response but without an ID.

Comment: there should be `custom` parameter. at the time of sending request send the id with it.

Comment: @sgt Could you be a bit more clear please. You mean the request that I send the retrieve the Billing Agreement ID? Which ID I am supposed to send where?

Comment: when you are sending the request of payment pass the record id in the custom field.paypal will return it. then save the response. by this u will get a link between them.

Comment: You need to fetch all the billing plans from PayPal and loop through them to find the plan that matches the definition you received in the billing agreement.